# Qt Designer UI template files

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I recently started playing with Qt and PyQt, then I learned about Qt Designer and the `.ui` files they generate in xml format.
I was wondering if there is a resource website for downloading the template `.ui` files? That would make life much easier to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know, it's not such practice in Qt to make template .ui files and then reuse them. If you want to reuse some ready UI components you can make Qt Designer Plugin and then use it. See documentation: [Adding Qt Designer Plugins](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/adding-plugins.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's no point to template `.ui` files because the only truly reusable element in them is styling. Layouts etc. are very application-specific. Certainly Qt style `.css`/`.qss` templates make sense. If any exist, you will find them with Google.

Comment: Maybe for You who seem to know so much... for us who are leaning it might be gold !